# How to show thumbnail for image when edit the node Drupal 8

Tags: entities, media

I need to add thumbnail for field image when I edit node
[image: When edit node]
[image]

Field settings and type:
Could you please explain How to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved that issue.

Me steps:

- go to image style and create new image style (/admin/config/media/image-styles).
- go to View modes (/admin/structure/display-modes/view)
- find Media section and create new view mode for media (/admin/structure/display-modes/view/add/media)
- go to Media bundles (/admin/structure/media).
- edit Image and go to Manage display (/admin/structure/media/manage/image/display)
- click edit to your view
  [image: /Users/ivo/Downloads/Manage display | Site-Install 2017-09-05 10-32-41.png]

Now we can configure Paragraph content type or Content type
[image: /Users/ivo/Downloads/Manage form display 2 | Site-Install 2017-09-05 10-37-08.png]